# pass parameter to embedded href='javascript:function(" + param + ");

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, leaflet

I'm trying to embed a call to a javascript function in a leaflet popup.

I'm binding the showPopup() function to each feature added to a map. The idea is when the user clicks on the feature, there is an href labeled "More info..." which should open a sidebar.

I'm attempting to pass in the features Code to the embedded 'javascript:getInfoPanelData(feature code here, say *PIPE* as example) to know which feature I'm working with. However, running this code in Chrome debugger yields

> Uncaught ReferenceError: PIPE is not defined at :1:18.

I've also tried to add single quotes around the parameter, but this yields a SyntaxError:

> Unexpected end of input (getInfoPanelData("red x" in debugger.

I'm not sure I can actually do what I need to do and am hoping someone can either point out my mistake or possible alternatives.

```js
/*** Code that builds the popup  ***/
function showPopup(feature, urlString) {
 console.info("onEachFeature: " + feature.properties.Code + " | " + feature.properties.NAME);

 var pkVal = parseInt(feature.properties.ParkType, 10);
 
 var parkIcon = "nationalpark-40.png";
 
 var retHtml = "<div id='popup' class='popup'>" + 
  "<h3 align='center'><img src='icons/" + parkIcon + "'/>" + feature.properties.NAME + "</h3>" + 
        "<p>State: " + feature.properties.State + " | parkCode: " + feature.properties.Code + " | parkType: " + pkVal + "</p>" + 
        "<p>Home Page: " + "<a href='" + urlString + "' target='_blank'>" + urlString + "</p>" + 
        "<p><a href='javascript:getInfoPanelData(" + feature.properties.Code + ");'> More Info...</a></p></div>";
 
 console.info("HTML: " + retHtml);
 
 return retHtml;
}
```

```html
/*** Code that binds the popup to the feature  ***/
    /*  Create our NPS Layer  */
  var npsCPs = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("data/NPS_4326_CPs.json", {
   pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {
     icon: npsIcon
    });
   },
   onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    var urlStr = "https://www.nps.gov/" + feature.properties.Code + "/index.htm";
    layer.bindPopup(showPopup(feature, urlStr));
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the code snippet:

```
<a href='javascript:getInfoPanelData(" + feature.properties.Code + ");'>
```

you *do* want to quote the `feature.properties.Code`. However, you can't just put a singe-quote in there as you're using single-quotes for the `href` property. You also can't just put double-quotes in there because you're using double-quotes for your string. You need to escape your quotes, for example:

```
<a href='javascript:getInfoPanelData(\"" + feature.properties.Code + "\");'>
```

Comment: That worked great. I made an assumption that having tried the \' in the string would be the equivalent of \". Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apologies. Done! Hope this helps others too!